# Is it safe to use async/await now?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, ecmascript-2017

Is it safe to use async-await in Javascript instead of
generators-promises now, knowing that the syntax has not made yet and
will be coming with the release of ES8?

What browsers can I count on it being available, and how common are the browsers where this syntax is not available?  By Safe I mean without some transpilers like babel?

Comment: What does "safe" mean? Safe for whom, where, against what possibility?

Comment: The syntax is not going to change, but you'll want to use transpilers for a long while. Does "safe" mean with or without transpilation?

Comment: `without some transpilers` - what is the environment you want to be `safe` in? browsers? definitely not, almost never until the world decides that internet explorer is finally **dead** - node, doesn't support it (yet)

Comment: To put things into perspective, `async/await` has not been officially released yet.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

There are two places I check whenever I have questions such as this:

The **Can I Use** website: http://caniuse.com/#search=await

And **Node Green**: http://node.green/#async-functions

Typically an answer is encouraged to include the relevant information to avoid link rot. But ironically this answer has exactly the opposite problem: this answer will rot (the information below will become invalid) long before the links above. So always check caniuse and node.green first:

From caniuse.com as of April 2019 :

- **IE** *: NOT SUPPORTED (most used version = 11)
- **Edge**: From version 15 (most used version = 17)
- **Firefox**: From version 52 (most used version = 65)
- **Chrome**: From version 55 (most used version = 72)
- **Safari**: From version 10.1 (most used version = 12)
- **Opera**: From version 42 (most used version = 58)
- **iOS Safari**: From version 10.3 (most used version = 12.1)
- **Opera Mini** *: NOT SUPPORTED
- **Android Browser** *: From 5 (most used version = 4.4)
- **Chrome for Android**: From version 55 (most used version = 71)

From node.green as of April 2019

- Node.js: From version 8.0.0

So depending on what you think is acceptable it is either safe or not safe. Note the following:

- This question was originally asked on 2017, and we have come a long way so async/await is much more safe to use now.
- By 2019, most mobile devices already support async/await.
- Node 8 is released on May 2017 so it should be safe to use async/await on Node.js unless your Node.js servers are very outdated.

Comment: Added most used version for caniuse data. It seems that the most used browser in the world is Chrome for Android at around 25% global usage

Comment: According to [the release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/RevisionHistory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014305-CH99-SW1), Safari 10.1 added support for ECMAScript 2016 and ECMAScript 2017 in Safari for macOS *and iOS*, including support for async and await.