# Using javascript Promise asynchronously

Tags: javascript, if-statement, promise

Here's the problem - I call a function and that optionally displays a dialog multiple times and waits for the user to press OK. Then after that - I want to do something else.

I think the solution requires use of Promise. But the async nature of the dialog.alert() call, is throwing me off.

```
function a()
{
if ( condition_ok )
{
   // there could be multiple dialogs
   //
   for ( int i = 0; i < 2; ++i )
      dialog.alert("press ok").then ( ()=> { console.log("done"); } );
  }
}
a();
// call b() after all the dialogs have been closed in a()
b();
```

Comment: `for ( int i = 0; i < 2; ++i )` ... int?

Comment: supposed to be pseudo-code...this is what happens when you're working with multiple languages at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in an environment that has arrow functions (which your code suggests you do) but doesn't support `async/await` (which is an excellent answer by @guest271314) you can use the following instead

```
function a() {
    var p = Promise.resolve();
    if (condition_ok) {
        // there could be multiple dialogs
        //
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
            p = p
            .then(() => dialog.alert('press ok'))
            .then(() => {
                console.log('done');
            });
        }
    }
    return p;
}
a().then(b);
```

Note: each dialog will wait for the previous to "close", which I think is what your code intended

Comment: I didn't try this because there seems to be some syntax issues. also what does p = p do??

Comment: .then on the next line. I have my way of chaining promises

Comment: makes sense - thanks. I've copied the code and will save it.

Comment: I've also accepted this answer. Both this and below from @grantonzhuang work - too bad i can't accept both. I decided to tag this one mainly because it displays the multiple alerts in the proper order - whereas the solution below displays in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async/await` or `Promise.all()` and `Array.prototype.map()`

```
async function a() {
  if ( condition_ok ) {
    // there could be multiple dialogs
    //
    for ( let i = 0; i < 2; i++ ) {
      let curr = await dialog.alert("press ok");
      console.log("done");
    }
  }
  return
}
// call b() after all the dialogs have been closed in a()
a().then(() => b(), err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: first time hearing of async/await - most probably not supported. Thanks though.

Comment: @dashman See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42183155/is-it-safe-to-use-async-await-now, https://caniuse.com/#search=await

Answer (score 0):

Use `Promise.all()`.

```
let targets = []
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    targets.push(dialog.alert('press ok'))
}
Promise.all(targets).then(([result1, result2]) => {
    b();
})
```

Comment: Thanks - works as expected - even if the 'for' loop is not entered.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that you need to wait for *all* your asynchronous `alert`s to be done before calling `b`. You could store all your asynchronous calls in an array and then use `Promise.all()` to make sure all of them are done before calling `b`. Here is how you could do that

```js
// Faking data/objects - START
const condition_ok = true;
const dialog = {
  alert() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve("Done");
    })
  }
}
const b = () => {
  console.log("Call b()")
}
// Faking data/objects - END

function a() {
  let promises = [];
  if (condition_ok) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
      promises.push(dialog.alert("press ok").then(() => {
        console.log(`Done with alert() for ${i}`);
      }));
    }
  }
  return promises;
}

Promise.all(a()).then(results => {
  // call b() after all the dialogs have been closed in a()
  b();
});
```

Comment: a() returns undefined of condition_ok is false.